# Passive voice with -게 되다

Tags: verb-endings, verb, north-korean, passive

As I know, the -게 되다 ending changes the verb into passive.
Also, the passive verbs can be formed by adding -되다 or -아지다, -어지다, -여지다.

But I faced some uses of -게 되다 in addition to these 2 passive forms.

11월 24일은 우리 겨레에게 통일의 밝은 서광을 비쳐준 력사의 날로 **기록되게 되였습니다**.

영광스러운 김일성조선의 새로운 강성번영의 시대가 **열려지게 되였습니다**.

Does this change the verbs meaning? Why 기록되였습니다 or 열려지였습니다 aren't used?

Comment: A note for language learners: Those are *North* Korean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As I know, the -게 되다 ending changes the verb into passive.

Not always, at least not in the English grammar sense of a passive verb form being one that shows that its grammatical subject is the "recipient" of an action, rather than the "doer" of an action - e.g. *to kick* is active, while *to be kicked* is passive.

X-게 되다 doesn't necessarily mean that something is the "recipient" of an action. 
Sometimes it can be translated as 'became' -  e.g. (to borrow 
HK Lee's example) 방이 깨끗하게 되다 - the room became clean - which is logically similar to 'the room is cleaned', so it is somewhat similar to a passive. But in other cases it could also be translated as "ended up" doing X.

It could be used with both passive *and* active forms, e.g.

**X 먹게 되다** - to end up eating X (active) 
**X에게 먹히게 되다** - to end up being eaten by X (passive)

> Also, the passive verbs can be formed by adding -되다 or -아지다, -어지다, -여지다.

-되다 can be part of some passive forms. However, -아지다, -어지다, -여지다 are not really passive- they focus the attention on something *changing* to become some way.

> But I faced some uses of -게 되다 in addition to these 2 passive forms. Does this change the verbs meaning?

As per my examples above, -게 되다 can make sense with both passive and active forms. It changes the meaning by focusing attention on the final state resulting from the action of the verb, showing that the end state is especially important or surprising.

Answer (score 1):

In sample, 기록됐습니다. 열려졌습니다. are more correct.

After 1950, Koreans are in a contact to English so that we are
accustomed to Korean translation of English passive sentence.

For instance, 지루하게 됐다(He is bored)

Even though Korean grammar contains a passive (which has a slight
difference compared to that of English [link](http://www.hani.co.kr/arti/society/schooling/267471.html)), 그는 지루해 한다 (active
voice) is more correct.

Another example : 방이 깨끗하다(active) 방이 깨끗하게
되다(passive) The room is cleaned.

Nowadays, a lot of examples of passive
style in here, may be more commonly used in Korean than active form. I
prefer 기록되게 되었습니다. 열려지게 되었습니다.

[link](https://namu.wiki/w/%EB%B2%88%EC%97%AD%EC%B2%B4%20%EB%AC%B8%EC%9E%A5/%EC%98%81%EC%96%B4)