# Difference between 도착하다 and 도착하게 되다

Tags: verb

Is there any difference between 도착하다 and 도착하게 되다?
In official style I have faced 도착하게 되다 several times. Why this verb is used instead of 도착하다?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passive voice with -게 되다](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/passive-voice-with-%ea%b2%8c-%eb%90%98%eb%8b%a4)

Comment: "~하게 되다" basically means that we couldn't help ourselves not to do it. We didn't have any other option so we had to do it and so it has been done that way. "~하다": I do/did it, probably in a way how I wanted to do it or because I wanted to do it. "~하게 되다": It just happened, regardless of whether I wanted to do it or not. ("하게 되다" stats a fact)

Comment: See also: [온라인 가나다: -하게 되다 vs -하다](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?qna_seq=148227)

Comment: 도착하다 by himself is not active verb. If it was an act that makes influence on something, the passive 도착하게 되다 would.be.understandable. But this case is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "도착하게 되다" is used when it is used as a part of narrative, expressing something like "...and that's how/why [we] arrived."

For example, we can say:

> 신호 문제로 기차가 다섯 시에 도착하게 되었습니다. = Due to signal issues, the train (arrived/will arrive) at five.
>
> 선생님의 권유로 축구를 시작하게 되었습니다. = I started soccer thanks to my teacher's suggestion.

In this case, it's possible that the train hasn't even arrived: what *happened* is the decision or circumstance that *caused* the train to arrive at five.

Of course, it's also possible to say the same without "-하게 되다":

> 신호 문제로 기차가 다섯 시에 (도착했습니다/도착하겠습니다).
>
> 선생님의 권유로 축구를 시작했습니다.

- Also I think you're confusing passive "-되다" (e.g., 생각되다, 파괴되다, 생산되다) with "-하게 되다": the latter has nothing to do with passives.

Answer (score 0):

도착(arrival) is a state, which is not his act. It is a his
 result.

나는 드디어 신의 영역에 도착했다. In the long run, I arrived at God's ability.

나는, 한 걸음 한 걸음 나아가다 보니, 목적지에 도착하게 됐다. It is
 observed that arrival is obtained through my each steps.

@ 도착하게 됐다 focuses to his guess to other's opinion.